# Ignore Self Part of Self

Tags: nlp, uima, ruta

I'm trying to detect person names based on dictionaries :

**Dictionary Start**

```
David Alberto 

David

Alberto
```

**Dictionary End**

**Input Start**

```
David Alberto
```

**Input End**

I want to anotate **David Alberto** as Person Name not **David** or **Alberto**.
I'm using below rule.

```
WORDLIST FirstNameList = 'en/ruta/dictionaries/FirstNames.txt';
DocumentAnnotation{-> MARKFAST(FirstNames, FirstNameList,true)};
FirstNames{PARTOF(FirstNames)->UNMARK(FirstNames)};
```

But As **David Alberto** is also part of **David Alberto** so it's also get unmark. Any idea how to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `PARTOFNEQ` (part of, not equal) considers the matched annotation and is only fulfilled if there is another one.

```
FirstNames{PARTOFNEQ(FirstNames)->UNMARK(FirstNames)};
```

However, this condition is one of the slowest in the current implementation (<= 2.6.0). I usually use something like:

```
FirstNames->{@FirstNames{-> UNMARK(FirstNames)} ANY; ANY @FirstNames{-> UNMARK(FirstNames)};};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Along with this I also want to detect Lipi Mittal as First Name.
And in Dictionary I have Lipi Mittal 
And in input I have Lipi Mittal and LipiMittal
But it is also annotating LipiMittal as FirstName. 
I resolved this using retain space logic.. But both rules are not working at a time..

Comment: Whitespace sensitive dictionary lookup can get quite annoying, e.g., is only one space allowed or also two, or a break? Which rule does not work is you make spaces visible? You could postprocess the annotation with somehting like `FirstNames{CONTAINS(CW,2,100), -CONTAINS(SPACE)-> UNMARK(FirstNames)};` with the appropriate filtering settings